Access has been blocked by CORS policy when redirecting to login.microsoft
I have a web app (javascript front-end with a .NET Core 6 Web API) and I am trying to add authentication via OpenIdConnect and my redirects to login.microsoft are blocked by a CORS, if I hit the refresh button on the browser the redirect to login.microsoft works and the authentication is fine, but if the redirect happens without refresh it does not work. What I am doing wrong or what is missing? I also configured CORS to allow redirects to login.microsoft
public static WebApplicationBuilder AddAuthenticationViaOpenIdConnect(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var serviceCollection = builder.Services;
        var configuration = builder.Configuration;

        serviceCollection.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // our authentication process will used signed cookies
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                // our authentication challenge is openid
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "oidc";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                // How middleware persists the user identity? (Cookie)
                options.SignInScheme =
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                // How Browser redirects user to authentication provider?
                // (direct get)
                options.AuthenticationMethod =
                    OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;

                // How response should be sent back from authentication provider?
                //(form_post)
                options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost;

                // Who is the authentication provider? (IDP)
                options.Authority = configuration["Azure:Authority"];

                // Who are we? (client id)
                options.ClientId = configuration["Azure:ClientId"];

                // How does authentication provider know, we are legit? (secret key)
                options.ClientSecret = configuration["Azure:Secret"];

                // What do we intend to receive back?
                // (code to make for consequent requests)
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;

                // Should there be extra layer of security?
                // (false: as we are using hybrid)
                options.UsePkce = false;

                // Where we would like to get the response after authentication?
                options.CallbackPath = configuration["Azure:CallbackPath"];

                // Should we persist tokens?
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                // Should we request user profile details for user end point?
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;

                // What scopes do we need?
                //options.Scope.Add("sid");
                //options.Scope.Add("email");
                //options.Scope.Add("acct");
                //options.Scope.Add("upn");
                //options.Scope.Add("groups");


                // How to handle OIDC events?
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect(configuration["Azure:RedirectOnSignOut"]);
                        context.HandleResponse();

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    // Where to redirect when we get authentication errors?
                    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/error");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            });

        return builder;
    }

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:50970",
                "https://login.microsoftonline.com/");
        });
});


Hi Andrei, after checking the issue, it sounds like front-end code issue or browser issue. So could you share more details about your javascript front-end.

Hi Jason, the front-end is written in Polymer and it lives under the same domain as the back-end (files are in wwwroot). There is no code related to authentication in front-end, everything happens on the server side. Also, the error message I get in the console is as follows: 'Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/587b6ea1-3db9-4fe1-a9d7-85d4c64ce5cc/oauth2/authorize?client_id=...' from origin 'https://localhost:50970' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' I am testing on Edge,Chrome - same prob.

It is recommended to create a new sample project which can reproduce the issue for us. It's hard to find the issue without debugging, hope we can find the root cause as soon as possible. And please hide the sensitive information in the repo. Thanks

if might depend on in which order you have the CORS middleware, try to move the UseCORS() middleware before or after AddAuthentication?.
